# Laravel 5.5 displaying Images in AWS S3 Bucket with Private permission

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5.5

I am develping a portal using Laravel 5.5 deployed on AWS server and using S3 bucket for image and file storage. The front end is developed with Angular.

I can successfully store the images on S3 Bucket with the following piece of code with "PRIVATE" Permissions:

```
$filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

$extension = $request->file('avatar_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

$filenametostore = $uuid.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

Storage::disk('s3')->put($filenametostore, fopen($request->file('avatar_image'), 'r+'));
```

My problem is how can I send the image url of the image uploaded to the front end to be displayed with PRIVATE permissions granted to the image.

Does letting the images set to PUBLIC has a security issue ??

Your feedback much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want your images to be publicly viewable to everyone on the Internet? Or should they be viewable to only certain authenticated users?

Comment: No the images shouldn't be public. and Yes to certain authenticates users only can see the images. This is a closed application.

Comment: I am looking to implement something like 'readStream()' method in Laravel

Comment: Yep, that's what I was getting at. You'd create a route for displaying an image from a private file on AWS.